# Delete any number of Columns in 2D dynamic array and resize the matrix size after column deletion

Tags: c

I am trying to delete first 20 columns from each of the slices of my 3D dynamic array. I guessed trying to write a function for 2D dynamic array would solve the problem which I would iterate over each of the levels of 3D array. I got an example in stackoverflow which I am trying to make work.

But the problem is the function  can not delete the whole column. Instead it only delete one element. Can anyone give me idea how to delete whole column from a 2D dynamic array?

```
void removeColumn(int** matrix, int col){ 
  MATRIX_WIDTH--;   
   for(int i=0;i<MATRIX_HEIGHT; i++)   {
    while(col<MATRIX_WIDTH)
    {
      //move data to the left
      matrix[i][col]=matrix[i][col+1];
      col++;
    }   matrix[i] = realloc(matrix[i], sizeof(double)*MATRIX_WIDHT);   }
```

My expected ouput is like
Sample input:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

sample output:

```
1 3 4
5 7 8
9 11 12
13 15 16
```

Update: here is the code which delete the column completely after using @frslm advice
  but matrix is not resizing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>


int** fill(size_t rows, size_t cols, int input[][cols])
{
    int i,j,count=1;
    int** result;
    result = malloc((rows)*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        result[i]=malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
        for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            result[i][j]=count++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}


void printArray2D(size_t rows, size_t cols,int** input)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            printf(" %4d",input[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void removeColumn(int** matrix, int col2del , int rows, int cols){ 
    int MATRIX_WIDTH = cols;
    int MATRIX_HEIGHT = rows;

    MATRIX_WIDTH--;   
    for(int i=0;i<MATRIX_HEIGHT; i++) {
        int curr_col = col2del; 
        while(curr_col<MATRIX_WIDTH)
        {
            //move data to the left
            matrix[i][curr_col]=matrix[i][curr_col+1];
            curr_col++;
        }
        //matrix[i] = realloc(matrix[i], sizeof(int)*MATRIX_WIDTH); // <- int, not double
        matrix[i] = realloc(matrix[i], sizeof (matrix[i][0])*MATRIX_WIDTH); 
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arRow,arCol;
    arRow =8;
    arCol = 9;
    int ar[arRow][arCol];
    int **filled;
    filled = fill(arRow, arCol, ar);
    printArray2D(arRow,arCol,filled);
    removeColumn(filled, 3,arRow,arCol);
    printf("After 3rd Column Delete.......\n");
    printArray2D(arRow,arCol,filled);
    return(0);
}
```

Output: last column duplicates

```
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27
   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36
   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45
   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54
   55   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63
   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72
After 3rd Column Delete.......
    1    2    3    5    6    7    8    9    9
   10   11   12   14   15   16   17   18   18
   19   20   21   23   24   25   26   27   27
   28   29   30   32   33   34   35   36   36
   37   38   39   41   42   43   44   45   45
   46   47   48   50   51   52   53   54   54
   55   56   57   59   60   61   62   63   63
   64   65   66   68   69   70   71   72   72
```

Comment: `int input[][cols]` is not used in `fill(size_t rows, size_t cols, int input[][cols])`.  Why have that parameter?

Comment: @chux does it make a difference? However,I was actually trying to learn different ways of passing the array.

Comment: It does make a difference.  Passing  unused parameters to a function without explanation detract and confuses the issue.  Hence the question to clarify.

Comment: `MATRIX_WIDTH--;` should only occur if `cols < MATRIX_WIDTH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You increment `col` until it reaches the end of the first row, but you never reset it for subsequent rows, which is why you end up removing only the first row's column.

Make sure you reset `col` at the start of each iteration:

```
void removeColumn(int** matrix, int col){ 
    MATRIX_WIDTH--;   
    for(int i=0;i<MATRIX_HEIGHT; i++) {
        int curr_col = col; // <- use a temporary `col` variable for each row
        while(curr_col<MATRIX_WIDTH)
        {
            //move data to the left
            matrix[i][curr_col]=matrix[i][curr_col+1];
            curr_col++;
        }
        matrix[i] = realloc(matrix[i], sizeof(int)*MATRIX_WIDTH); // <- int, not double
    }
}
```

---

**Edit** (in response to OP's edit):

Ensure that `removeColumn()` updates the number of columns (`cols`) after resizing the matrix; one way to do that is by using a pointer: `int *cols` as a parameter instead of `int cols` (don't forget to pass in an address, `&arCol`, when calling this function). Also, I suggest getting rid of the unnecessary `MATRIX_HEIGHT` variable:

```
void removeColumn(int** matrix, int col2del, int rows, int *cols){
    int MATRIX_WIDTH = --(*cols);

    for(int i=0;i<rows; i++) {
        int curr_col = col2del; 
        while(curr_col<MATRIX_WIDTH)
        {
            //move data to the left
            matrix[i][curr_col]=matrix[i][curr_col+1];
            curr_col++;
        }
        matrix[i] = realloc(matrix[i], sizeof(matrix[i][0])*MATRIX_WIDTH); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :). Yes now it deletes the whole column completely. But still there is a problem. The whole matrix_width should be reduced by 1. Here the last column is replicating itself. How can I prevent that?

Comment: @Makau Your `realloc()` call resizes your row. Since you reduce  `MATRIX_WIDTH` by 1 at the start of the function, then `realloc()` should already give you a row with one less column. If you're still accessing elements of that duplicate column, then you're likely accessing elements that are out-of-bounds - you're actually hitting undefined behaviour at this point. In that case, just don't access the duplicate column; you aren't allowed to anyway.

Comment: Rather than `realloc(matrix[i], sizeof(int)*MATRIX_WIDTH)` and hope code used the correct matching type, code `realloc(matrix[i], sizeof matrix[i][0] * MATRIX_WIDTH)`   to remove OP's coding error and make code easier to review and maintain.

Comment: @frslm  Yes I am no accessing the last columns. But as you said like we are decreasing the MATRIX_WIDTH by 1 at the beginning I should get  the final matrix as reduced size. But it's not happening.

Comment: @chux I used your code chunk. But no change happens.

Comment: @Makau You'd have to show the rest of your code, specifically how you set `MATRIX_WIDTH`, allocate `matrix`, and access `matrix` after calling `removeColumn()`.

Comment: @frslm I have edited it. Like how i used it in my code.

Comment: @Makau Please create a new question since you're asking something different now, or edit your original question instead of my answer.

Comment: @frslm Thank you for your kind advice. I am then editing the question.

Comment: @Makau, you're trying to edit my answer again; like I said, just add your code to your question instead or create a new question and include it there.

Comment: @frslm sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Makau, no worries - I've updated my answer to address your second point. In the future though, create a separate question for every new question you have.

Comment: `int &cols` is not valid C code.  Perhaps you are thinking of another language?

Comment: @chux Right you are! Forgot I'm not in C++; I'll edit the answer.

Comment: You may also want to consider  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677417/delete-any-number-of-columns-in-2d-dynamic-array-and-resize-the-matrix-size-afte?noredirect=1#comment86375408_49677417)

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you pass the width and height, and update the width:

```
void removeColumn(int** matrix, int col, int* width, int height)
{
    int j, i;
    for (j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
        if (col == *width-1) {
            continue;
        }
        for (i = col; i < *width; ++i) {
            matrix[j][i] = matrix[j][i+1];
        }
        // this is not necessary, but I'm adding as requested
        matrix[j] = realloc(
            matrix[j],
            sizeof(int) * (*width - 1)
        );
    }
    --(*width);
}
```

You could also avoid dynamic memory allocations, avoiding memory defragmentation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int max_width, max_height;
    int width, height;
    int* values;
} matrix;

void removeColumn(matrix* matrix, int col)
{
    int y, i;
    for (y = 0; y < matrix->height; ++y) {
        if (col == matrix->width-1) {
            continue;
        }
        i = col + matrix->height * y;
        while (i < matrix->width) {
            matrix->values[i] = matrix->values[++i];
        }
    }
    --matrix->width;
}

void printMatrix(matrix* matrix)
{
    int y, x;
    for (y = 0; y < matrix->height; ++y) {
        for (x = 0; x < matrix->width; ++x) {
            printf("%d ", matrix->values[x + matrix->width * y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int y, x = 0;
    matrix matrix;
    matrix.max_width = 4;
    matrix.max_height = 4;
    matrix.width = 4;
    matrix.height = 4;
    int values[4][4];
    matrix.values = &values;
    for (y = 0; y < matrix.height; ++y) {
        for (x = 0; x < matrix.width; ++x) {
            int i = x + matrix.width * y;
            matrix.values[i] = i % 10;
        }
    }

    printMatrix(&matrix);
    removeColumn(&matrix, 1);
    printf("===\n");
    printMatrix(&matrix);
}
```

Tested using: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php

**ADDED**

> But when the array size is too big then do we have any other option
>   but using dynamic array

If you want to make a resizable array, you could use a single `malloc` when allocating the array and use a `realloc` when the `width` will be greater than `max_width` or the `height` will be greater than `max_height`.

Nevertheless, I believe we should try to avoid lots of dynamic allocations using `malloc` or `realloc`, because they're slow (though most of the time you won't notice), they can severely defragment memory and the way you did it generates lots of unnecessary cache misses.

You should also grow them more than required, for instance, exponentially, if you don't know that you will need to resize the array several times. That's how hashes and dynamic arrays are usually implemented (properly).

You may find, for instance, several JSON, XML and HTML C libraries without dynamic memory to avoid its pitfalls, and in many professional video games, a huge `malloc` might be used to avoid lots of them and simple arrays are used liberally.

- [Why is realloc eating tons of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189987/why-is-realloc-eating-tons-of-memory)
- https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2014/11/04/please-grow-your-buffers-exponentially/
- http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/data-locality.html
- https://codefreakr.com/how-is-c-stl-implemented-internally/
- http://gamesfromwithin.com/start-pre-allocating-and-stop-worrying
- [CppCon 2014: Mike Acton "Data-Oriented Design and C++"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX0ItVEVjHc)

Of course, you can use dynamic memory, but it's better to understand its pitfalls for better decisions.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it.
But when the array size is too big then do we have any other  option but using dynamic array? Like 1680*16*12 size of 3D array.

Comment: Thank you for your time and detailed answer :)

Comment: You're welcome, @Makau. By the way, using a simple pointer (instead of a double pointer) and a single malloc you may also allow matrixes with any specified dimensions number. It would require more work, but wouldn't assume that a matrix has only two dimensions without the need of implementing a function for each dimensions number.